# Had anyone else attempted to steal the Philosopher's Stone before Voldemort?

Tags: harry-potter

As Nicholas Flamel was 665 years old by the time of HP&TPS, It's likely that the Philosopher's Stone had been in existence for at least 500 years.

Considering the extraordinary lengths to which it was protected during the events of Harry's first year, it seemed to me that the protection was a relatively new occurrence, something that had never been done before (harboring it inside a school at the very least doesn't seem to be something to make a habit of).

However, it's difficult to believe that in the 500 years that it had already existed, no one other than Voldemort had thought to attempt to steal it to gain unnaturally long life.

Is there any evidence that anyone had attempted to steal it before this? Was it as heavily guarded before this point?

Comment: Just speculation: As Mr. Flamel was a very talented wizard, I suppose he didn't feel the need to put extra measures to ensure the stone's security, trusting his own capabilities. That was until a very terrible and probably more talented threat rose in form of Tom Riddle, which forced him to take extra precaution, given the consequences and probability of a probable theft

Comment: I like to think he was safely obscure until some idiot printed his biography on a chocolate frog wrapper and made him a target

Comment: the stone's existence in Flamel's possession makes no sense. it everyone knew, why Flamel wasn't asked to share his findings so wizards could create more stones, and why no one took the stone by force. no matter how talented F was, it's eternal life and riches -even more tempting than the elder wand. F and his wife wouldn't have a quiet moment. maybe PS being her first book JKR made a few beginner's mistakes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking through the books and Pottermore I've found no additional instances of anyone attempting to steal the stone.

As to whether it was guarded, Flamel himself is an extremely clever/gifted wizard shown by his ability to create the stone to begin with, so he would be more then apt to protect the stone from any ordinary threats, Voldemort being the exception as an extraordinary threat.